# Add jQuery with a block on TOP of the head

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, magento

I have an extension in magento which adds a block in the header for loading jQuery:

```
<reference name="head">            
     <block type="page/html" 
            template="csdev/embedjquery/embed_jquery.phtml" 
            output="toHtml" 
            name="csdev_embedjquery" />
</reference>
```

The content of the block is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $.noConflict();
    alert(jQuery);
</script>
```

The problem is that jQuery will be added too late, after prototype. It needs to added before prototype, so i can execute the `noConflict()` function.

Also, since I don't want to overwrite the magento head-template or the magento head-block, I added the following:

```
output="toHtml"
```

but that's too late :(...

Is there a solution such as `"add this block on top of the reference (head) with output='toHtml'"`?

I tried:

```
before="-"
```

but it doesn't seem to work, because I wrote:

```
output="toHtml"
```

My Magento Version is 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are adding it as a phtml file, instead of a JS file. Try adding this instead into page.xml, within default -> root -> head (around lines 37 to 61):

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
```

Then create a folder within /js called jquery, and upload jquery.js into that file. At the end of the jquery.js file, append the noConflict method call. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But then i will change a magento system file. also there won´t be the execution from the "jQuery.noConflict()" Method. So it will conflict with prototype.

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve this by using the below snippet in the `/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/layout/local.xml` file.  If we use this layout override, we don't need to edit any core files.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text" name="external.cdn.jquery" before="-">
                <action method="setText">
                    <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]></text>
                </action>
            </block>        
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

As you can see we are loading jQuery from an external CDN.  This will be loaded on all the pages.  But in case you wanted to limit it to any specific pages use the page handle instead of the `<default>` tag - eg: for home page `<cms_index_index>`.

Comment: Hey, it seems that this is what i looked for! :)
I will try it and then tell you if it worked! :)

Comment: Hmmm, that doesnt work. Magento won´t give out the Block-Text, in the  root-phtml needs to be an output over $this->getChildHtml("...") :( Maybe there´s no solution without changing phtml-files

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldn't work, as I have used this code in many of my sites.  In case you missed this, there is some good articles in http://classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout

Comment: Of course there are reasons. On the site you posted just the "local.xml" will be edited. Also, changes in reference to "header" will be written AFTER core javascripts. but i need it on "top" of the header. also then i need to write "output='toHtml'", otherwise the block won´t get displayed.